# SSH.NET C# send Yes or No to linux server

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I'd like to execute a script on linux server from C# program, I have a sample code as below.

```
var ssh = new SshClient("ip", "user", "password");
var cmd = ssh .CreateCommand("./executescript");
cmd.BeginExecute();
var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.OutputStream);
var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but I can't finish executing the script because it will ask a question like 'would you like to do that? yes or no', how can I send yes or no to linux from C#?

Could anyone give me some suggestion? Or any tips?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh.RunCommand("yes")` ? It may work.

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work... I found ssh expect can solve this problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
            SshShell shell = new SshShell(<host>, username, pass);
            shell.Connect();
            shell.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;
            string outputt = shell.Expect(new Regex(@"[$#>]"));
            shell.WriteLine("cd <Path> ");
            outputt = shell.Expect(new Regex(@"[$#>]"));
            shell.WriteLine("nohup bash executescript.sh & ");
            outputt = shell.Expect(new Regex(@"[$#>]"));
            shell.WriteLine("exit");
            outputt = shell.Expect(new Regex(@"[$#>]"));

            shell.Close();
```

it works for me.